# Codeigniter 3 routing with and without a parameter

Tags: codeigniter, routes, codeigniter-3

How do you set up routes in Codeigniter 3 in the following case:

If I want to all products, I use this URL:

```
https://www.domain.local/product
```

If I want to show a specific product, I use this URL:

```
https://www.domain.local/product/123
```

So far, the only way I can get this to work is by using two separate routes:

```
$route['product']        = "Catalog/product";
$route['product/(:any)'] = "Catalog/product/$1";
```

How can I combine these routes into one? I can find no documentation that refers to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your approach is the correct approach:

> Routes will run in the order they are defined. Higher routes will
>   always take precedence over lower ones.

and

> Route rules are not filters! Setting a rule of e.g. ‘foo/bar/(:num)’
>   will not prevent controller Foo and method bar to be called with a
>   non-numeric value if that is a valid route.

In your controller function you'll check if the parameter exists.

```
function product($id=0){
   if ($id){
      // your code for product where id corresponds to $1 (from link)
   }else{
     // your code if no product id in link
   }
}
```

see [Codeigniter URI Routing - Wildcards](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html?highlight=routes#wildcards)